# Nuxt dynamic component import

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to import my components dynamic in nuxt.
The following error is my problem:

> Expected component elements to have 'v-bind:is' attribute

**Template**

```
<template>
  <v-tabs v-model="selectedTab" background-color="grey darken-2" dark>
   <v-tabs-slider />

  <v-tab v-for="tab in tabs" :key="tab.title" :href="`#tab-${tab.title}`">
    {{ $t(tab.title) }}
  </v-tab>

  <v-tab-item
    v-for="tab in tabs"
    :key="tab.title"
    :value="`tab-${tab.title}`"
    :transition="false"
    :reverse-transition="false"
  >
    <component :is="componentInstance(tab.component)" />
  </v-tab-item>
 </v-tabs>
</template>
```

**Method**

```
methods: {
  componentInstance(component) {
    return () => import(`~/components/tabs/${component}`)
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because webpack doesn't know about the chunk that it splits.

Comment: I have seen examples with a computed property that work. What is the difference to my method?

Comment: @PatelPratik I cant see any difference to my code beside he is using a computed prop.